# Round off up to two decimal places

Tags: java, math

I want to round of up to two decimal places. That round off should happen to the very basic level which we have learned in school.

```
new BigDecimal(inputValue).setScale(2, What should I use here?);
```

I've tried mostly all available parameters but all works partially.

Can't share example because there could be so many, but just want my value to be round off up to two decimal place at very basic level.

I'm little tired of searching the exact parameter to accomplish this task.

Note: Basic level means not using `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is this:

```
new BigDecimal(inputValue).setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP)
```

The `RoundingMode.UP` is just many of the options you can use in the `RoundingMode` class.

There are many more. For instance, here we use the `UP` which rounds everything up. You can see all the values here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

**Edit:** I understand what you want to do. You want `45.423 to become 45.42 while 45.55 to become 45.56`. But in Java, anything with a `.5` in the end would round down or as it's known to floor it. You can't round `45.555 to 45.56` without using `UP`, but that also means that `45.243` would become `45.25`. So there is a tradeoff. No one solution for all.

Comment: Mall, Not work, It gives 42.43 from 42.4240 ..! It should be only 42.42 (Very Basic)

Comment: check my last comment ..!

Comment: @CookingJava That's called flooring (rounding down)

Comment: Nope, It gives 45.45 from 45.4550. But I want 45.46 (Very Basic)

Comment: @Carcigenicate, FLOOR gives same results... 45.45 from 45.4550. But I want 45.46 (Very Basic)

Comment: Mistake. Use `UP`. Thats what you want. You have to decide what you want. Thing is that in programming 0.5 rounds down only.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
new BigDecimal(inputValue).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

This way values 0.005 => 0.01, and values 0.004 => 0.0.

Also, see this table for the behavior of other RoundingMode options:

```
+--------------+----+------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+
| Input Number | UP | DOWN | CEILING | FLOOR | HALF_UP | HALF_DOWN | HALF_EVEN | UNNECESSARY               |
+--------------+----+------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+
| 5.5          | 6  | 5    | 6       | 5     | 6       | 5         | 6         | throwĘArithmeticException |
+--------------+----+------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+
| 2.5          | 3  | 2    | 3       | 2     | 3       | 2         | 2         | throwĘArithmeticException |
+--------------+----+------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+
| 1.6          | 2  | 1    | 2       | 1     | 2       | 2         | 2         | throwĘArithmeticException |
+--------------+----+------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+
| 1.1          | 2  | 1    | 2       | 1     | 1       | 1         | 1         | throwĘArithmeticException |
+--------------+----+------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+
| 1            | 1  | 1    | 1       | 1     | 1       | 1         | 1         | 1                         |
+--------------+----+------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+
| -1           | -1 | -1   | -1      | -1    | -1      | -1        | -1        | -1                        |
+--------------+----+------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+
| -1.1         | -2 | -1   | -1      | -2    | -1      | -1        | -1        | throwĘArithmeticException |
+--------------+----+------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+
| -1.6         | -2 | -1   | -1      | -2    | -2      | -2        | -2        | throwĘArithmeticException |
+--------------+----+------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+
| -2.5         | -3 | -2   | -2      | -3    | -3      | -2        | -2        | throwĘArithmeticException |
+--------------+----+------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+
| -5.5         | -6 | -5   | -5      | -6    | -6      | -5        | -6        | throwĘArithmeticException |
+--------------+----+------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+
```

Please refer to the documentation for a full explanation.
Source:[Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)

Comment: That's available on the documentation

Comment: Correct. I just put it here, so future users don't need to go both places to fix their issues.

Comment: Good thing you did :)